# Even prime question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove the following implication.
If p > 2 is an even prime, then p > (2^100) + 1.
i really didnt get this question. can anybody help please?

Comment: Exactly what part of the question are you having a problem with?

Comment: Mathematically, the implication is right because there is no even prime $p>2$ and $A\implies B$ is always true if $A$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis in always false. A false hypothesis $p$ implies any proposition $q$. See [modus ponens $p\implies q$ truth's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens#Justification_via_truth_table).